# 「Binding transformer name NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData is deprecated since macOS 10.14」という警告の処置

Tags: xcode, storyboard

**Cocoa-Bindings**を使って**NSTableView**にデータを表示しています。**NSTableView**は**セルベース**です。テーブルの各カラムは、**Array Controller**に**arrangedObjects**というコントローラーキーでバインドされています。

一方、**Array Controller**は、各カラムのソートディスクリプタを保存するため、**UserDefaults Controller**にバインドされています。
表題の警告は、この**Array Controller**と**UserDefaults Controller**のバインドの際、**Value Transformer**に、deprecateされた、**NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData**を設定していることによって発生しているようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ですが、この**Value Transformer**を設定する欄のプルダウンメニューには、同じくdeprecateされた、**NSUnarchiveFromData**と、**NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData**の２つしかありません。おそらくは、**NSUserDefaults**にアーカイブされているデータを展開する設定だからではないかと想像します。

質問は、この**Value Transformer**に、deprecateされた**NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData**以外のものを設定することはできるのか、可能だとしたら何を設定すれば良いのかということです。

ご教授、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Ha it's very funny that so many japs code in English, you must understand English then, right? If so what are doing in the jap site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData**は、deprecateなので、使ってはいけません。替わりは、**NSSecureUnarchiveFromData**ですが、そのまま置き換えても、ダメです。
**NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer**のサブクラスを作成し、そこで、値の**evaluation**を許可する必要があります。（デフォルトでは許可されていないため）
また、対象のアプリが、以前からのデータ（ソートディスクリプタ）を持っている場合も、**NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer**のサブクラスを作成して、古いデータをアンアーカイブする処理が必要になります。
下のリンクは、上に書いた説明を具体化したコードを含むサンプルです。（この回答とサンプルコードは、Appleの開発者向けサポートとのやり取りをサマライズしたものです）

[サンプルXcodeプロジェクト](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1vQKMykwuQ0HUYTkcgCRbpCAOF0Wc9hYY)